# Loading 3rd-Party Drivers before Fedora 14 Installation

Tags: linux, fedora, drivers, software-installation

My server is equipped with a megaraid controller that cannot be identified by most linux installer. I have to load it's driver before installation can proceed. I know how to do it with CentOS that simply type "linux dd" when prompt "boot:", and I will be able to load drivers from a usb flashdisk. But when it comes to Fedora 14, it seem there is no way for me to have any opportunity to load drivers before installation, so can't it find the harddisk :(
Anyone here has some advises?

Answer (score 2):

dd stands for driverdisk, in fact on fedora is driverdisk instead.

http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html

```
> driverdisk <partition> --source=<url>
> --biospart=<biospart> [--type=<fstype>]
> 
>     *
>       <partition> — Partition containing the driver disk.
>     *
>       <url> — URL for the driver disk. NFS locations can be given in the form
> nfs:host:/path/to/img.
>     *
>       <biospart> — BIOS partition containing the driver disk (for
> example, 82p2).
>     *
>       --type= — File system type (for example, vfat or ext2).
```

You can provide even a network resource:

```
driverdisk --source=ftp://path/to/dd.img
driverdisk --source=http://path/to/dd.img
driverdisk --source=nfs:host:/path/to/img
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you get the `boot:` prompt only if you use the DVD install for Fedora.  The LiveCD doesn't give you the option.